# Phalcon router to match variable depth folder structure

Tags: router, phalcon, subdirectory

I have the need to configure a Router in Phalcon in order for it to match URI like the followings:

- http://www.help.com/{controller}/{action}/{param...}
- http://www.help.com/subfolder1/{controller}/{action}/{param...}
- http://www.help.com/subfolder2/{controller}/{action}/{param...}
- ... and so on...

Is there a way to do it in a single set of instruction without adding each one as a specific route?

Thank you very much, pretty new to this framework.

Comment: Please see these Q&A : [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668224/phalcon-router-and-loader-for-subfolder-structure-getting-bigger-how-to-set-up) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743731/phalcon-router-doesnt-react-to-subfolders-and-namespace-declaration) & [this](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/298/sub-folder-inside-controllers-folder-)